# Disable auto-completion of remote branches in Git Bash?

Tags: windows, bash, git

I'm working on a fairly large git repo with a couple of thousand (remote) branches. I am used to using auto-completion (using [TAB]) in the console (Git Bash in that case), so I unconsciously do that for git commands, too.

e.g. I'd type

```
git checkout task[TAB]
```

with the effect that the console stalls for often minutes. Is there a way to limit auto-completion to local branches only?

Comment: Note: since 2011, you have (with Git 2.13, Q2 2017) `git checkout --no-guess ..., or export GIT_COMPLETION_CHECKOUT_NO_GUESS=1`: both would disable branch completion. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43747486/6309).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), you can disable (some of) the branch completion.

```
git checkout --no-guess ...
# or:
export GIT_COMPLETION_CHECKOUT_NO_GUESS=1
```

See [commit 60e71bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/60e71bbceae9c81abed60a01449dbcbdc3ec89d6) (21 Apr 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b439747](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b439747bc1074f6f325987d6f2b1a38119d3b863), 01 May 2017)</sup>

As documented in [`contrib/completion/git-completion.bash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b439747bc1074f6f325987d6f2b1a38119d3b863/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L32-L38) now:

> You can set the following environment variables to influence the behavior of the completion routines:
>
> ```
> GIT_COMPLETION_CHECKOUT_NO_GUESS
> ```
>
> When set to "1", do not include "DWIM" suggestions in `git-checkout`
>    completion (e.g., completing "foo" when "origin/foo" exists).

Note: [DWIM is short for **D**o **W**hat **I** **M**ean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM), where a system attempts to anticipate what users intend to do, correcting trivial errors automatically rather than blindly executing users' explicit but potentially incorrect inputs.

> ### `completion`: optionally disable checkout DWIM
>
> When we complete branch names for "`git checkout`", we also complete remote branch names that could trigger the DWIM behavior. Depending on your workflow and project, this can be either convenient or annoying.
>
> For instance, my clone of `gitster.git` contains 74 local "`jk/*`" branches, but origin contains another 147.
>   When I want to checkout a local branch but can't quite remember the name, tab completion shows me 251 entries. And worse, for a topic that has been picked up for pu, the upstream branch name is likely to be similar to mine, leading to a high probability that I pick the wrong one and accidentally create a new branch.

---

Note: "picked up for pu": see a [What's cooking in `git.git`](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=147501860131712&w=2): it starts with:

> Commits prefixed with '`-`' are only in **'`pu`' (proposed updates)** while commits prefixed with '`+`' are in '`next`'.

This is part of the [Git Workflow Graduation process](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows#_graduation).

> `pu` (proposed updates) is an integration branch for things that are not quite ready for inclusion yet

---

> This patch adds a way for the user to tell the completion
>   code not to include DWIM suggestions for checkout.
>   This can already be done by typing:
>
> ```
> git checkout --no-guess jk/<TAB>
> ```
>
> but that's rather cumbersome.
>
> The downside, of course, is that you no longer get completion support when you *do* want to invoke the DWIM behavior.
>   But depending on your workflow, that may not be a big loss (for instance, in git.git I am much more likely to want to detach, so I'd type "`git checkout origin/jk/<TAB>`" anyway).

Comment: @sehe I have added references and documentation on the "pu" part.

Comment: Sadly creating an alias which uses this option internally does not seem to work. Only providing the option directly on the CLI results in only local branch completion. :(

Comment: I believe as of now the best solution (which seems to fully answer OP's request) is `GIT_COMPLETION_CHECKOUT_NO_GUESS=1` while using `git switch` since 2.23 @VonC

Answer (score 26):

I'm assuming that you are using the `git-completion.bash` script, and that you **only** care about `git checkout`.

To accomplish this, I just changed one line in the definition of the `_git_checkout ()` function in `git-completion.bash`:

```
<       __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs '' $track)"
---
>       __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_heads '' $track)"
```

My understanding is that this only affects the tab-completion action (because of its location within the `*` case of the switch-case statement).

Comment: Steps: `sudoedit /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git`, then change the line mentioned in the @erik.weathers's answer, reopen bash and voilà! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I agree with @andre.orvalho, this is definitely the better solution now.

Comment: I actually added a new method: __git_rco ().  rco (or remote checkout) uses the old behavior with `refs`.  __git_checkout () now just does `heads`.  I have an alias rco = checkout.  This way, you can still get the old behavior if you want.

Comment: I added an extra case where `"")` uses `__git_heads` but `*)` uses `__git_refs`.  This makes it so it only suggests heads but if you have something typed out already (i.e. `t`) it will give me any matching ref (i.e. `tag/sometag`).  If this continued to be too much, it could also match on `tag/` -> `tag/sometags` etc.

Comment: If you installed git-completion via brew, it's located here: `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash`

Answer (score 11):

If you installed git-completion via homebrew, it's located here:
`/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash`

Following [erik.weathers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18626043/1570970) above, I made the following change so autocompletion can work for both local and remote based on the current prefix. By default, it'll only search local, but if I specify `origin/…` it'll know I want to search remote branches too.

In the `_git_checkout ()` method, change

```
    __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs '' $track)"
```

to:

```
    # only search local branches instead of remote branches if origin isn't specified
    if [[ $cur == "origin/"* ]]; then
        __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs '' $track)"
    else
        __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_heads '' $track)"
    fi
```

Of course, you can change `origin` to something else or you can have it search through through a list of remote prefixes if you have more than 1.

Comment: imo the most complete answer

Answer (score 10):

You can hack /etc/bash_completion.d/git

You'll need to edit `__git_refs ()`

Note that the change in behaviour will apply every where (so even with git push/pull where you might not want it to). You could of course, make a copy of the function or pass an extra parameter, but I leave that to you

Comment: Yeah, so it turns out that tags *and* remote branches are slow.
I changed `refs="refs/tags refs/heads refs/remotes"` to only `refs="refs/heads"` and commented out the whole "Try to find a remote branch that matches the completion word" section. Not pretty, but WFM :-)

Comment: Mmm. you aren't by any chance using a git repository over the network? I've never seen _that pathetic_ performance with git (however: `git add` is notoriously slow in windows)

Comment: No, I'm using git locally. It's just a friggin' huge repo, I guess. `git for-each-ref | wc -l` returns 11000 ...

Comment: But yes, Git is noticeably slower on Windows than on *nix/Mac.

Comment: Any idea how to do this for zsh?

Comment: @GalderZamarreño I got this working by modifying  /usr/share/zsh/4.3.11/functions/_git

Answer (score 4):

You could think that you just the local branches with the alias `co` and all the branches with the complete command `checkout`.

You could perform the following. In your .bashrc, you redefine the `_git_checkout()` function. You let this function unchanged, except the end:

```
if [ $command -eq "co" ]; then
  __gitcomp "$(__git_refs_local '' $track)"
else
  __gitcomp "$(__git_refs '' $track)"
fi
```

Then, you just have to define a new function, `__git_refs_local`, where you remove the remote stuff.

Comment: `-eq` is for comparing numbers, the comparison should be `if [ $command = "co" ]; then`.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying `$(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash` is not a good idea because it will be overwritten every time you update Git through Homebrew.

Combining all the answers I overwrite only `_git_checkout` function from the completion file in my `.bash_profile` after sourcing the completion file:

```
_git_checkout ()
{
  __git_has_doubledash && return

  case "$cur" in
    --conflict=*)
      __gitcomp "diff3 merge" "" "${cur##--conflict=}"
      ;;
    --*)
      __gitcomp "
      --quiet --ours --theirs --track --no-track --merge
      --conflict= --orphan --patch
      "
      ;;
    *)
      # check if --track, --no-track, or --no-guess was specified
      # if so, disable DWIM mode
      local flags="--track --no-track --no-guess" track=1
      if [ -n "$(__git_find_on_cmdline "$flags")" ]; then
        track=''
      fi
      # only search local branches instead of remote branches if origin isn't
      # specified
      if [[ $cur == "origin/"* ]]; then
        __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs '' $track)"
      else
        __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_heads '' $track)"
      fi
      ;;
  esac
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Carey Metcalfe wrote [a blog post](https://cmetcalfe.ca/blog/git-checkout-autocomplete-local-branches-only.html) containing a solution that also edits the auto-completion function, but with slightly newer code than other answers. He also defines an alias `checkoutr` that keeps the old auto-complete behavior in case it’s ever needed.

In short, first create the `checkoutr` alias with this command:

```sh
git config --global alias.checkoutr checkout
```

Then find `git-completion.bash`, copy the `_git_checkout` function into your shell’s RC file so that it gets redefined, and inside that function, replace this line:

```sh
__git_complete_refs $track_opt
```

with the following lines:

```sh
if [ "$command" = "checkoutr" ]; then
    __git_complete_refs $track_opt
else
    __gitcomp_direct "$(__git_heads "" "$cur" " ")"
fi
```

See [the blog post](https://cmetcalfe.ca/blog/git-checkout-autocomplete-local-branches-only.html) for more details and potential updates to the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Git Bash myself, but if this is the same as mentioned in 
http://tekrat.com/2008/04/30/bash-autocompletion-git-super-lazy-goodness/, you should be able to replace git **branch -a** with a plain **git branch** in

```
_complete_git() {
  if [ -d .git ]; then
    branches=`git branch -a | cut -c 3-`
    tags=`git tag`
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${branches} ${tags}" -- ${cur}) )
  fi
}
complete -F _complete_git git checkout
```

(in your .profile or similar) and get what you want.

Comment: Hm. This function would be an addition to standard Git behavior (at least I don't have that function anywhere). What I want is to do less than the default. Editing `__git_refs()` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

FWW here is a hack to __git_complete_refs that does the trick

```
__git_complete_refs ()
```

{
    local remote track pfx cur_="$cur" sfx=" "

```
while test $# != 0; do
    case "$1" in
    --remote=*) remote="${1##--remote=}" ;;
    --track)    track="yes" ;;
    --pfx=*)    pfx="${1##--pfx=}" ;;
    --cur=*)    cur_="${1##--cur=}" ;;
    --sfx=*)    sfx="${1##--sfx=}" ;;
    *)      return 1 ;;
    esac
    shift
done
echo cur_ $cur_ > a
 if [[  $GIT_COMPLETION_CHECKOUT_NO_GUESS != 1 || $cur_ == "origin"* ]]; then
    __gitcomp_direct "$(__git_refs "$remote" "$track" "$pfx" "$cur_" "$sfx")"
  else
    __gitcomp_direct "$(__git_heads  "" "$cur_")"
  fi
```

}