# Disable auto-completion of remote branches in Zsh?

Tags: git, zsh

This is related to [Disable auto-completion of remote branches in Git Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623649/disable-auto-completion-of-remote-branches-in-git-bash).

Anyone knows how to do the same with zsh?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
zstyle :completion::complete:git-checkout:argument-rest:headrefs command "git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads 2>/dev/null"
```

Explanation:

Typing `git checkout <Control-x><h>` invokes `_complete_help` which exposes the internals of how zsh's completion system would act if you pressed TAB in the current context (instead of pressing `<Control-x><h>`).  From this it is possible to see that zsh would invoke the `__git_heads` function to complete names of git branch heads.  If you then type `which __git_heads`, you can see that these branch head names are obtained via:

```
_call_program headrefs git for-each-ref --format='"%(refname)"' refs/heads refs/remotes 2>/dev/null
```

Luckily for us, `_call_program` is designed specifically to allow the user to change the default behaviour.  So the above `zstyle` command instructs zsh to use an alternative `git for-each-ref ...` invocation instead of the built-in one, and you can see that in the invocation above, I removed the `refs/remotes` parameter.  The first parameter to `zstyle` is the completion context, and here it means "whenever the completion system is requesting completion for the `headrefs` tag when the user is completing an argument for `git checkout`.  So this `zstyle` will only affect `git checkout`, and not any other `git` sub-commands.

Comment: How would one split the remote and local into two separate sections in the auto-complete? E.g. I'd love to have the special heads (`HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, etc), then local branches, then remote branches. It's non-obvious to me how that would be done. If it's easy to expand your answer, that would be swell. If not, I'll open a new question.

Comment: There's *probably* a way to do that - after all, there is a grouping mechanism (search for `group-name` and `group-order` in the manual) but I don't know off-hand how to split the various heads out into these groups - so probably worth a separate question.

Comment: Anyone know how to get this to work with prezto? Presumable, the command would start with `':prezto:module:completion:git-checkout`, but I haven't been able to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 5):

By typing `git checkout <Ctrl-X><H>` you see a bunch of tags, some which seem relevant are:

```
$ git checkout
tags in context :completion::complete:git-checkout:argument-rest:
    remote-branch-names-noprefix              (__git_describe_branch __git_describe_commit __git_remote_branch_names_noprefix _git-checkout _git) 
    heads-remote                              (__git_describe_branch __git_describe_commit __git_heads_remote __git_heads __git_commits __git_tree_ishs _git-checkout _git) 
    [...]
```

At first sight, we need to change `remote-branch-names-noprefix`'s behavior to stop providing remote branch names with no prefix.

To double check, let's see what entries these tags are associated with, use:

```
$ zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
$ zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing "%d":'
$ git checkout T<Tab>
Completing "remote branch name":
T3522-plugins_and_stuff  T7482
Completing "local head":
T7626-async
```

In the parenthesis following the tag names above, there is a chain of commands which led to an autocomplete entry being generated for that tag. In `remote-branch-names-noprefix`'s chain you can see `__git_remote_branch_names_noprefix` which seems relevant. Look in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git`:

```
(( $+functions[__git_remote_branch_names_noprefix] )) ||
__git_remote_branch_names_noprefix () {
  declare -a heads

  branch_names=(${${${${(f)"$(_call_program remote-branch-refs-noprefix git for-each-ref --format='"%(refname)"' refs/remotes 2>/dev/null)"}#refs/remotes/}#*/}:#HEAD})
  __git_command_successful $pipestatus || return 1

  __git_describe_commit branch_names remote-branch-names-noprefix 'remote branch name' "$@"
}
```

You can see how `_call_program` is used to define `remote-branch-refs-noprefix`. We want to change this definition in `git-checkout`'s case. By replacing it with "echo", it will stop providing autocomplete entries:

```
zstyle ':completion::complete:git-checkout:argument-rest:remote-branch-refs-noprefix' command "echo"
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `__git_heads` now only checks local branches, but the completion files call `__git_refs` instead.

I hacked this in by applying this patch to `git-completion.bash`, which is proxied through to by the zsh `_git` command:

```
--- git-completion.bash.old 2015-04-02 16:09:38.000000000 -0700
+++ git-completion.bash     2015-04-02 16:10:24.000000000 -0700
@@ -1032,13 +1032,7 @@
                    "
            ;;
    *)
-           # check if --track, --no-track, or --no-guess was specified
-           # if so, disable DWIM mode
-           local flags="--track --no-track --no-guess" track=1
-           if [ -n "$(__git_find_on_cmdline "$flags")" ]; then
-                   track=''
-           fi
-           __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs '' $track)"
+           __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_heads)"
            ;;
    esac
 }
```

It's not a perfect solution, but it works for my use cases and makes completion instant instead of 10 seconds.

Comment: The code seems to have changed a lot since 2015 and the patch won't apply. Could you tell us which function definition this is in, please?

Answer (score 0):

No one answer don't help me. Try this:

```
$ git checkout <Ctrl+X><H>
tags in context :completion::complete:git::
    argument-rest  (_arguments _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:git-checkout::
    argument-rest options  (_arguments _git-checkout _call_function _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:git-checkout:argument-rest:
    remote branches tree-ishs modified-files  (_alternative _git-checkout _call_function _git) 
    remote-branch-names-noprefix              (__git_remote_branch_names_noprefix _alternative _git-checkout _call_function _git) 
    heads commit-tags commit-objects          (_alternative __git_commits __git_tree_ishs _alternative _git-checkout _call_function _git) 
    heads-local                               (__git_heads_local __git_heads _alternative __git_commits __git_tree_ishs _alternative _git-checkout _call_function _git) 
    commit-tags                               (__git_tags_of_type __git_commit_tags _alternative __git_commits __git_tree_ishs _alternative _git-checkout _call_function _git) 
    modified-files                            (__git_files __git_modified_files _alternative _git-checkout _call_function _git)
```

You can found in this output functions, which generates completion for command. You can override any of this function on your `.zshrc`. Put this **at the very top of config file**:

```
__git_heads_remote() {}
```

After that, you will not see remote heads on your completion. You can do this for any function.

Answer (score -2):

You can disable auto-completion on `git checkout` by adding this line to your `.zshrc` file:

```
compdef -d git checkout
```

Comment: I was looking for a way that avoided auto-completion of remote branches. I'd like to have auto-complete of local branches though.

Comment: @GalderZamarreño Afraid that's beyond the scope of my zsh knowledge; might try the zsh list; they seem like helpful folks.