# Get default remote push and default remote branch

Tags: git, push

From a script, I would like to get the default push remote and the default push branch.

For the recall, git will choose the remote between these settings, in this order:

- `branch.<name>.pushRemote`
- `remote.pushDefault`
- `branch.<name>.remote`
- very last default

  - origin if `config push.default current`
  - NULL if `config push.default upstream`

I can't find any reference how git is choosing this last default origin, but it seems static.

Default remote branch can be:

- `branch.<name>.merge` if `config push.default upstream`
- current branch name otherwise

Now, I would like a safe way to get both default push remote and default push branch.

1. I could use `git config --get`, but I'll have to resolve myself the behoavior according to `config push.default`, and it seems a bit risky.
2. I would prefer to use one of these:

   - `git for-each-ref --format='%(push:short)' refs/heads/mybranch`
   - `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref=loose mybranch@{push}`

Finally, I have two questions:

1. `git for-each` and `git rev-parse` returns a path like `origin/mybranch`. How can I split between the remote name and the branch name (a remote name can contains `/`'s).
2. Is there a safer function between the both? (in all my tests, they always return the same output).

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), there is a new syntax, where the "`--format=...`" option for "[`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref)" learned to show
the name of the '`remote`' repository and the ref at the remote side
that is affected for '`upstream`' and '`push`' via "`%(push:remotename)`"
and friends.

See [commit 1b58686](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b586867dba322c911cc9b4441e2be130ba76cd5) (07 Nov 2017), and [commit cc72385](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc72385fe350d4d7bc64f84e8817dbdfe27b04fe) (05 Oct 2017) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit 9700fae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9700fae5ee93dd0928cb82afb7b2fd49295e28d2) (07 Nov 2017) by [J Wyman (`whoisj`)](https://github.com/whoisj).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 093048b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/093048b22913be23fe45635e8723d3aa3a185ff3), 15 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### `for-each-ref`: let upstream/push optionally report the remote name
>
> There are times when e.g. scripts want to know not only the name of the upstream branch on the remote repository, but also the name of the remote.
>
> This patch offers the new suffix `:remotename` for the upstream and for
>   the push atoms, allowing to show exactly that. Example:

```
$ cat .git/config
...
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://where.do.we.come/from
    fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remote/origin/*
[remote "hello-world"]
    url = https://hello.world/git
    fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remote/origin/*
    pushURL = hello.world:git
    push = refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    pushRemote = hello-world
...

$ git for-each-ref \
  --format='%(upstream) %(upstream:remotename) %(push:remotename)' \
  refs/heads/master
refs/remotes/origin/master origin hello-world
```

> The implementation chooses *not* to **[DWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM)** the push remote if no explicit
>   push remote was configured; The reason is that it is possible to DWIM this
>   by using

```
%(if)%(push:remotename)%(then)
    %(push:remotename)
%(else)
    %(upstream:remotename)
%(end)
```

> while it would be impossible to "un-DWIM" the information in case the
>   caller is really only interested in explicit push remotes.
>
> While `:remote` would be shorter, it would also be a bit more ambiguous,
>   and it would also shut the door e.g. for `:remoteref` (which would
>   obviously refer to the corresponding ref in the remote repository).

---

> ### `for-each-ref`: let upstream/push report the remote ref name
>
> There are times when scripts want to know **not only the name of the
>   push branch on the remote, but also the name of the branch as known
>   by the remote repository**.
>
> An example of this is when a tool wants to push to the very same branch
>   from which it would pull automatically, i.e. the `<remote>` and the `<to>`
>   in `git push <remote> <from>:<to>` would be provided by
>   `%(upstream:remotename)` and `%(upstream:remoteref)`, respectively.
>
> This patch offers the new suffix `:remoteref` for the `upstream` and `push`
>   atoms, allowing to show exactly that. Example:

```
$ cat .git/config
...
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://where.do.we.come/from
    fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remote/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "develop/with/topics"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop/with/topics
...

$ git for-each-ref \
    --format='%(push) %(push:remoteref)' \
    refs/heads
refs/remotes/origin/master refs/heads/master
refs/remotes/origin/develop/with/topics refs/heads/develop/with/topics
```