# how to make git checkout <tab> show only the branches I have locally

Tags: bash, git

When I want to check a branch to checkout to and I don't remember the exact name, I can't use Tab-completion, as the pool it uses is the branch pool of remote.

How can I make the Tab only look at the git branch pool (i.e. only choose from the local branches I created / already checkedout)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable auto-completion of remote branches in Git Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623649/disable-auto-completion-of-remote-branches-in-git-bash)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+tab+completion+local+branches

Comment: https://cmetcalfe.ca/blog/git-checkout-autocomplete-local-branches-only.html

Answer (score 1):

One way is to modify the standard code completion script for `git checkout`, example (& credit) below:

https://gist.github.com/mmrko/b3ec6da9bea172cdb6bd83bdf95ee817

Answer (score -3):

If i understand your problem you can first run

```
git branch
```

if the branch is locally.
Else you can

```
git branch --all
```

if the branch is on repository and you didn't checkout it yet.
Then you can

```
git checkout <branchName>
```

Comment: You are just *showing* the available branches, not affecting how tab completion for Git works.