# no tab completion when using git checkout alias

Tags: git, git-config

I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43747486/3512538) on "how to disable git checkout auto-complete" (specifaclly, using the `--no-guess` part, as the `export` didn't seem to work.)

I have a *.gitconfig* file with the following entry:

```
[alias]
    co = checkout
```

and so, when I use `git co`  it works ok:

```
git co <TAB>
Display all 1417 possibilities? (y or n)
```

and when using `git co --no-guess` :

```
git co <TAB>
Display all 738 possibilities? (y or n)
```

1. Does that mean I already have 738 local branches? If so, how can I remove unwanted branches from?
2. when changing the alias in my *.gitconfig* to `co = checkout
   --no-guess` it continues to work as before (i.e. only adding `'--no-guess'` explicitly after `git co` does the trick. why is
   that?

**Seems to be a git bug... is it?**

Comment: I doubt 1417 and 738 are the numbers of branches. I rather thing these are counts of local files tab completion is trying to complete.

Comment: After the linked answer there is a comment "*Sadly creating an alias which uses this option internally does not seem to work. Only providing the option directly on the CLI results in only local branch completion.*"

Comment: Didnt see that comment. Nevertheless aliases such as `git branch -d` do work for me so this is puzzeling

Comment: Tab completion works for me in aliases, even in aliases with shell functions. This one seems to be a bug in git.

Answer (score 1):

It means you have 738 "things".  A thing can be a local branches (unlikely - check with `git branch`), or a tag which is *much* more likely.  Hopefully you have a naming convention which allows you to distinguish branches and tags, and the distinguishing feature is a prefix not a suffix. Type enough of a prefix to limit to branches.