# How not to display tags in git autocompletion?

Tags: bash, git, bash-completion

When using completion in git, for example on the git checkout command, all tags are returned.
I have more and more tags, which makes reading quite unpleasant.

```
user:~/repo$ git branch
  prod
  staging
  master
  user_branch1
  user_branch2
```

```
user:~/repo$ git checkout user_
  user_remote_branch3
  user_branch1
  user_branch1-2023-06-19T1042-6386b7b427
  user_branch1-2023-06-19T1555-cf61155208
  user_branch1-2023-07-19T1818-808a0fa125
  user_branch1-2023-07-19T1839-8c379cf567
  user_branch1-2023-07-24T1125-4b50cd52a2
  user_branch2
  user_branch2-2023-06-21T1457-c323d6697a
  user_old_branch4-2023-06-21T1818-25006b3d62
  user_old_branch5-2023-03-02T1512-63fa5377f7
```

I truncated my example but currently for 3 active branches, I have more than 30 results

The --no-guess option doesn't remove the tags.
It is not possible to delete these tags on the remote for history purposes.

It seems to me that a possible solution could be :

- no longer retrieve tags for each git pull/git fetch (I don't know how to automate it without having to add `--no-tags` on each command)
- delete existing ones

But it looks fragile. All it takes is one oversight to have to delete all the tags again.
And I might have to use these tags one day.

Based on reading [Disable auto-completion of remote branches in Git Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623649/disable-auto-completion-of-remote-branches-in-git-bash/18626043#18626043)

I see it's possible to edit git's behavior by editing the file.
\usr\share\bash-completion\completions\git

I have confirmed its presence but its understanding remains a mystery to me.
Is there a way to limit auto-completion to branches only?

Thanks

Comment: Given that this is a question about configuring autocompletion in bash, it might be better asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Does the completion script you're using provide better completion if you use the more modern `git switch` instead of `git checkout`? `git checkout <tag>` is valid, so it makes sense why it would provide tag completions. On the other hand, `git switch` only accepts a branch name (unless you `--detach`).

Comment: @Brian61354270 `git switch` give exactly the same result. I still see tag with the autocompletion

Comment: Using `zsh`, `git switch` only suggests branch names in autocompletion.

Comment: Hello. Thank for your suggestion. But unfortunately, I cannot do change that

Answer (score 0):

Provided you're using the official bash completion script for Git, adding this into your `~/.bashrc` should produce the desired effect of `git checkout` tab-completion not showing or completing tags:

```bash
_git_checkout() {
    __git_complete_refs --dwim --mode=heads "$@"
}
```

Then, of course, re-open your terminal emulator, or re-login over SSH, or you can simply run `exec bash -l`.

Comment: Thank for your reponse.
Did not see any change.
I try to edit directly /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
But it broke the completion
`user:~/repo$ git --version
git version 2.25.1`

I tried all time by restarting the VM

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the system file for this. After changing your `.bashrc`, you'll need to restart your shell. As a test, you could paste this into your terminal and press enter: `_git_checkout() { __git_complete_refs --dwim --mode=heads "$@"; }` -- that'll modify how git completion works *just for your current shell*.

Comment: Still the same.
user:~$ _git_checkout() { __git_complete_refs --dwim --mode=heads "$@"; }
user:~$ cd repo
user:~/repo$ git checkout user_
  user_remote_branch3
  user_branch1
  user_branch1-2023-06-19T1042-6386b7b427
  user_branch1-2023-06-19T1555-cf61155208

Comment: What's the output from `git tag`?

Comment: a list of at least a thousand.
But if I restrict with `git tag -l user*`. It is the list that I want to remove